# Erratic jquery performance on IE8

Tags: jquery

I am having a tough time debugging my ajax request using jquery.

Basically whenever I make a ajax request using jquery in IE, sometime the request never return and the page seems to 'hang'. The code is seen below:

```
function lookup_thread_list(inputTopicID,inputPg,inputRank,inputRef) {      
    $('#thread_list').html("<div class='default_white' align='center' style='padding:10px'><img src='./images/loading.gif'></div>");
    $('#reply_stat').html('');
        pausecomp(100);         
    $.post("grp_list_thread.php", {topic_id: ""+inputTopicID+"",pg: ""+inputPg+"",rank: ""+inputRank+"",ref: ""+inputRef+""}, function(data){
        if((data.length >0)) {
            $('#thread_list').html("data");

        }
    });
```

}

What I am trying to do is to first put a loading  bar gif at a #reply_stat div (found inside the #thread_list div) so that the user will know that the page is loading. Next, I make a jquery to the page grp_list_thread.php to get the list of thread associated with that topic.

On Firefox, all is ok. However on my IE8, sometime the loading bar will appear at the #reply stat and hang there. It is as though the next few javascript code is no executed.

Have look through many form and tried things like using .append instead of .html but nothing works. The tricky part is that it happens erratically with no exact pattern that I can see.

Really need help from all u jquery expert on this!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem!
The reason for the no show on IE8 is because of the meta tag

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

that I have included.
Once removed, it is working fine on IE.

Comment: I have also realised that all ajax returned page should have a <html><body> structure. All my pages used to omit that 2 tags and just start with <div>.